# Font size in page not found error page is increased

Tags: support, design, 404-not-found, font-size

In the page not found error page, the font-size for the text is increased recently. Previously the font-size was less and the UI looked good.

Is the design change on purpose or any impact with any other design changes? I can verify the font-size issue in Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange.

Current UI:

> [image: Current UI]

With less font-size. Few days before, it was looked like that:

> [image: Expected UI]

GIF for removing the font-sizes with the current UI:

> [image: GIF]

Comment: I suppose this was done to make the error page responsive.